# Preciso de ajuda para mostrar todos os itens de um array com Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, for

Estou utilizando o AXIOS para acessar a API e consigo retornar somente o primeiro resultado.

Copiei apenas uma parte do código abaixo, mas tudo funciona perfeitamente quando eu insiro o índice [0].

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
                    <p><b>Nome: </b> ${item.products[0].name} </p>  
                    <p><b>Preço: </b> R$ ${item.products[0].priceMin} </p>`
```

Tentei de inúmeras formar utilizar um laço for para mostrar os 12 itens, mas não há forma de fazer isso funcionar.

Acredito que a requisição está correta, pois, quando executo um `console.log(item.products);`consigo visualizar os 12 resultados.

De que maneira posso fazer com que apareçam todos os resultados dentro do HTML?

Código que não está funcionando:

```
function showResults (item) {                   
            var tamanho = item.products.length;
            for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {                     
            document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block'
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
                <p><b>Nome: </b> ${item.products[i].name} </p>  
                <p><b>Preço: </b> R$ ${item.products[i].priceMin} </p> `
                console.log(item.products);
            }
```

Estou aprendendo, então fui juntando o que aprendi com os tutoriais. Não sei se tem algum absurdo.

Comment: Pode fornecer um exemplo do JSON retornado?

Comment: Como é o laço que você está usando?

Comment: nos apresente seu laço for, talvez esteja nele o problema

Comment: Acabei de editar com o meu laço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a cada ver que esse for itera estás a aoagar o conteúdo anterior e re-escrever...

Em vez de usar `document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =` deves usar `+=` para acrescentar, e não substituir.

Dito isso, eu sugiro usares o `.map` ou o `.reduce` que a meu ver são mais práticos para esse tipo de tarefas:

```js
function showResults(item) {
  const html = item.products.reduce((html, product) => {
    return html + `
       <p><b>Nome: </b> ${product.name} </p>  
       <p><b>Preço: </b> R$ ${product.priceMin} </p>
    `;
  }, '');
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block'
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Ontem esqueci de citar este caso:

<p><b>Imagem: </b> <img src="${item.products[i].thumbnail.otherFormats[i].url}" /></p>

De que forma posso acessar os valores dentro de otherFormats? Estou recebendo undefined.

Comment: @JoãoFernandoZanato nesse caso tens de ter outro `.map` ou `for` dentro do que mostrei e usar a mesma lógica. Nesse caso a array a iterar é `product.thumbnail.otherFormats`